# How to automatically shut down an RDS instance when Amazon turns it on every 7 days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

So we all know that Amazon turns on your stopped RDS instance every 7 days for an update but it doesnt shut it down. I want to know how to set up AWS to turn off the instance automatically when Amazon turns it on.

I don't want to have a scheduled lambda code run. Like every day or something. I want it to register and that it somehow knows that the RDS instance has started and then it stops it. I can probably do a snapshot and then delete it but I want to know how to do it this way.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/

Comment: The better method would be to take a **snapshot**, then delete the RDS instance. When you need it again in future, you can create a new instance from the snapshot. The ability to stop an RDS instance should not be interpreted as a method to keep it permanently stopped.

Comment: Thank you for answering. These instances are being used maybe once every month and the person accessing it doesn't won't to be bothered with creating a new instance. We use SNS to send us an email when it detects instances being up so isn't there a way for SNS to send that mail to CloudWatch so CW can react to that mail and then trigger Lambda?